# Not able to install mediawiki for ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, installation, apache2, mediawiki

I have used [this link](https://hostpresto.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-mediawiki-on-ubuntu-16-04/) for MediaWiki installation. Used all steps up to "Configure Apache for Mediawiki".

While enter this command:

```
sudo a2ensite mediawiki sudo a2dissite 000-default
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Site mediawiki already enabled
ERROR: Site sudo does not exist!
ERROR: Site a2dissite does not exist!
Enabling site 000-default.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
  service apache2 reload
```

What is the problem?

**edit**

Thanks for your Reply .Yes, I tried

1. `sudo a2ensite mediawiki`
2. `sudo a2dissite 000-default`

After first command I got

```
Site mediawiki already enabled
```

And after second command  I got

```
Site 000-default disabled.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
service apache2 reload
```

so ,I executed `service apache2 reload` 
the output is

```
service apache2 reload
apache2.service is not active, cannot reload.
```

Answer (score 2):

That is actually two commands; you missed the like break in the middle.  Run it like this:

```
sudo a2ensite mediawiki
sudo a2dissite 000-default
```

That is, enable the site `mediawiki` and disable the site `000-default`.

Comment: I have tried whatever you recommended. Please see edit above.